# "No Stages/Jobs jobs for this pipeline" for branch pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline

Given the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
---
stages:
  - .pre
  - test
  - build

compile-build-pipeline:
  stage: .pre
  script: [...]
  artifacts:
    paths: [".artifacts/build.yaml"]

lint-source:
  stage: .pre
  script: [...]

run-tests:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"'
  trigger:
    strategy: depend
    include:
      artifact: .artifacts/tests.yaml
      job: "compile-test-pipeline"
  needs: ["compile-test-pipeline"]

build-things:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"'
  trigger:
    strategy: depend
    include:
      artifact: .artifacts/build.yaml
      job: "compile-build-pipeline"
  needs: ["compile-build-pipeline"]
...
```

The configuration should always run (any branch, any source). Tests and build jobs should be run only on the default branch.

*However*, no jobs are run for merge requests, and manually triggering the pipeline on branches other than the default one give the error `No Jobs/Stages for this Pipeline`.

I've tried explicitly setting an always run rule using `rules: [{if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE'}]` to the jobs in the `.pre` stage, but no dice.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

As per the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#pre-and-post):

> You must have a job in at least one stage other than .pre or .post.

In the above configuration, no jobs other than the ones in `.pre` are added on merge request events, hence no jobs are added at all.

Comment: _no jobs other than the ones in .pre are added on merge request events_, what about `test` and `build` ? Why are they not considered as individual stages independent of `.pre` ?

Comment: My pipeline was executed on a merge request - so `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` was not the default branch (as the related jobs' rules require); hence they were not added to the pipeline. This resulted in no other jobs being added aside from the ones in `.pre` and `.post` stages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you added this info into the question: `However, no jobs are run for merge requests`

`CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is not available in MR-based events. Here is an fragment from official docs:

```
The commit branch name. Available in branch pipelines, including pipelines for the default branch.
**Not available in merge request pipelines or tag pipelines.**
```

When working with MR and willing to check against branch name, you might want to use:
`CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` or `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME`

List of envs [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)